# twitter like resize image in url php

Tags: php

I was checking the way twitter processes images, and I realised this:

**NORMAL IMAGE** this is the url of a normal image

https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DgM7YnNVQAAcouD?format=jpg

**RESIZED IMAGE** this is the url of the same image but reduced to 360px wide

https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DgM7YnNVQAAcouD?format=jpg&name=360x360

I think that by doing that, twitter avoids creating new image files "thumbs"

in this case the var `name` determines the resizing....

How do I get this type of resizing avoiding the use of new thumbs?

Comment: Use something like [glide](http://glide.thephpleague.com/) or implement the change on the fly with gd.. define allowed sizes, create once..

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, everything that am I saying here is just a supposition.

I dont think that twitter converts an image everytime it receives a request, they must store all the sizes they use for each image, and from the example you showed this is provably what is happening there: When the user requests image.png with height x width, twitter checks if file exists ( if true, it shows the image ), if false, it converts the original image, stores it and then shows it. Either way it is better to save the sizes you need.